# What is the actual meaning of velocity space is isotropic or density of velocity points is same everywhere?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, boltzmann-equation

I am studying Maxwell Boltzmann distribution law, In the derivation I came across a statement and I am not sure if my interpretation is right or wrong.
Statement is "since velocity space has been assumed to be isotropic, the density of velocity points can be taken as independent of inclination of $v$ to the axes" I think it implies that if we consider two unit volumes $dv_1 $ and $dv_2$ situated at $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively,then number of molecules having velocities $V_1 $ to $V_1+dv_1$ is same as number of molecules having velocities between $V_2$ to $V_2 +dv_2$ since velocity space is isotropic then number density of velocity points is same for every point in space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful: your explanation would mean the probability density for the velocity is uniform i.e. $P(v_1)dv = P(v_2)dv$ or $P(v)=const$ which is *not* the case for the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution!

"Isotropic" means that there is no preferred *direction* i.e. there might be a preferred magnitude but if you take a velocity *vector* it can be oriented in *any* direction randomly. Therefore, changing the axis (i.e. rotating your system by a given angle) does *not* change the orientation distribution as the probability of being aligned to, for instance the $x$-axis is the same as the one for the $y$-axis or for any other axis so you can "shuffle" them however you want.

In other words, imagine you take a box of gas molecules and you sample the velocities. You get a distribution $P_1$. Then you rotate the box however you want and you sample the velocities again: you get $P_2$. Then if the system is isotropic, $P_1=P_2$.

In a simple 1-dimensional example, if you take a random velocity, it will have the same probability of pointing left or right. So that $P(v_x)=P(|v_x|)$, i.e. the sign does not matter: the probability is just a function of the magnitude. It does not matter how you define left or right: you and your mirror image will see the same probability distribution (this is not the case if there is flow: for example, the direction a river flows depends on what side of the river you sit :D )

In more general terms and in 3D, if we write the probability of finding a given vector $\vec{v}$ as $P(\vec{v})$ we can re-write it as
$$P(\vec{v})=P(v, \theta, \phi)$$ i.e. as the probability of finding a velocity vector with *magnitude* $v$ and orientation in space given by the two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ (remember spherical coordinates?!).

"Isotropic" means that $P(\vec{v})$ is *independent* of $\theta$ and $\phi$ i.e. it is a function of *only* the magnitude
$$P(\vec{v})=P(v)$$
meaning that the probability of finding $v$ in $[v_1, v_1+dv]$ is different than that of finding $[v_2, v_2+dv]$ *but* whatever the magnitude you find, there will be no preferred direction: the sign and the angle the vector makes with any axis is completely uniform.

Indeed, the MB distribution is $$P(\vec{v})\sim e^{-v^2}$$ and only depends on the magnitude $v$ and not on the vector orientation or its sign (because of the square).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite able to get what your interpretation means. The statement

> Since velocity space has been assumed to be isotropic, the density of velocity points can be taken as independent of the inclination of $v$ to the axes.

means, that there is no preferred direction in space. The probability of the velocity vector of the particle to point in one direction is equal to the probability of the velocity of the particle to point in any other direction. So that if you rotate your coordinates by some angle, nothing will change.

Answer (score 1):

You may have mixed up isotropic and homogeneous.  Homogeneous means it's the same for any region in space.  Isotropic means it's the same no matter how you rotate it.   A distribution with spherical symmetry, that is denser around $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ than for higher values of $|v|$, is isotropic but not homogeneous.  So it is not necessarily the same for every point in velocity space as in your example, in fact it usually isn't.
The statement means you can define your axes pointing in any directions; under the rotaions of space the same distribution will still look the same.